# Startup Applications didn't run my script

Tags: command-line, bash, startup-applications

I add an item in Startup Applications as follows:

[image: Edit Start up Program]

I repeat the command here, for your convenience:

```
gnome-terminal --command  "sleep 30;export PATH=$PATH:/home/erik/Downloads/geckodriver_dir;python ~/Dropbox/BashScripts/fjucheckin.py"
```

It is expected, after I enter my office and turn on my laptop, to open an gnome-terminal, then run the python script `fjucheckin.py` to open a Firefox window and then automatically check in on my behalf, and then wait for me pressing a key to close the Firefox window. But it turns out that no gnome-terminal or Firefox window shows up.

Afterwards I run the whole above-mentioned `gnome-terminal --command  "sleep 30;export PATH=$PATH:/home/erik/Downloads/geckodriver_dir;python ~/Dropbox/BashScripts/fjucheckin.py"` command manually, and a terminal shows up and closes within a second. No Firefox window shows up.

And I run the `sleep 30;export PATH=$PATH:/home/erik/Downloads/geckodriver_dir;python ~/Dropbox/BashScripts/fjucheckin.py` manually, and it works.

The python script `fjucheckin.py` is as follows, if you need it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
#import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(1000) # seconds
driver.get("http://140.136.251.114/Aiamis/Login.aspx")
#assert "Python" in driver.title

#Account
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txtAccount")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("...")
elem.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

#Password
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$txtPwd")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("...")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

#// Get a handle to the open alert, prompt or confirmation
WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert = driver.switch_to.alert;
#// And acknowledge the alert (equivalent to clicking "OK")
alert.accept();

elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("差勤/日誌填寫");
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_link_text("專任助理簽到退"));
hover.click().perform();

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ddlPlanToday")
Select(elem).select_by_value("500767");

driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_rdSignType_0").click();

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_txtTodayOther")
elem.clear()
description = u"研究資料整理"
elem.send_keys(description)

driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_btnSignToday").click()

#pause
raw_input()
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your commands in quotes:

```
gnome-terminal --command 'bash -c "sleep 30 ; export PATH=$PATH:/home/erik/Downloads/geckodriver_dir ; python ~/Dropbox/BashScripts/fjucheckin.py ; bash"'
```

Having "bash" at the end of the commands will keep the terminal open.

Comment: It works. But why add the `bash -c` at the beginning?

Comment: Multiple commands would not work at all unless another shell was spawned.  The gnome-terminal man page is vague on the usage and behavior of --command.